# insert query in database table get me problem

Tags: python, postgresql

```
for jp_number in datadict:
ct_id = "".join(datadict[jp_number]).replace("'", '')
  
insert_query = """INSERT INTO dwb_weekly_snapshot(jp_number, ct_id) VALUES(%s, %s)"""
cursor.execute(insert_query, (jp_number,ct_id))
```

I am getting 'M': 'operator does not exist: character varying = numeric' as Error

jp_number is varchar(20) and ct_id (text) in table I tried exaclty above query

Same Erro coming for

```
update_query = """update dwb_weekly_snapshot set ct_id= %s where jp_number = %s """
 cursor.execute(update_query, (ct_id, imnumber))
```

Comment: jp_number  is primary number in table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jut converted inumber = str(imnumber) It worked becaulse its a varcharb 20 in table

Answer (score 0):

you are saying Jp_number is varchar(20) in you table, then why are you casting to int in your execute statement? remove the int(xx) and try

Comment: actually I am using for loop and jpnumber value is coming from that by iterating datadictionary in python @saro please reglance qn i edited it